# Add a Rectangle Selector inside a Figure Canvas subclass

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rectangles

I am working with matplotlib (I am quite new using matplotlib) and I would like to add a rectangle selector to select specific areas on a image. I tried to build the Rectangle selector inside a subclasss (FigureCanvasQTAgg). I want the rectangle selector inside the subclass since it is just part of the project. I used as reference the code here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/rectangle_selector.html
However, when I run the code the rectangle selector doesn't work. Could you help me solving the problem?

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import PySide6.QtGui
import copy 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib #Library for creating static, animated, and interactive visualizations in Python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolBase, ToolToggleBase
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton #intEnum BACK = 8, FORWARD = 9, LEFT = 1, MIDDLE = 2, RIGHT = 3
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector 

matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg 

class ImageDisplayer(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    
    def __init__(self,DisplayData=None):
        self.DisplayData=DisplayData
        self.Figure, self.Axis=plt.subplots(1, 1, constrained_layout=True)
        self.Figure.patch.set_facecolor([1,1,1,0.5])
        self.Axis.set_facecolor([1,1,1,0.1])

        super(ImageDisplayer, self).__init__(self.Figure) 

        self.RecSelector=RectangleSelector(self.Axis, self.onselect, interactive=True, state_modifier_keys=dict(move=' ', clear='escape', square='shift', center='ctrl'))
        self.Figure.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.toggle_selector)

        plt.show() 
        
    def onselect(eclick, erelease):
        print(f'Starting position: ({eclick.xdata}, {eclick.ydata})')
        print(f'End position: ({erelease.xdata}, {erelease.ydata})')

    def toggle_selector(self,event):
        if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and self.RecSelector.active:
            print("Rectangle selector deactivated")
            self.RecSelector.set_active(False)
        if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not self.RecSelector.active:
            print('Rectangle selector activated')
            self.RecSelector.set_active(True)

ImageDisplayer()
```

Comment: What is the error message? Which line do you receive the error?

Comment: I don't receive any error message. It is just that the rectangle doesn't appear when selecting. I checked and it doesn't enter to the onclick function, but I cannot find the reason.

Comment: You have only `print` statements under the `onselect` method. According to the `if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not self.RecSelector.active:` condition, the `RecSelector` object is only activated if the 'A' and 'a' key is pressed and if it is not activated.